# Connect to dlt-daemon from DLT Viewer

Tags: logging, dlt-daemon

I installed DLT Viewer on my ubuntu . I have a simple  C++ Cmake app which sends logs to DLT Deamon and those logs of the app can be views in other terminal using

> dlt-receive -a localhost

command as specidfied in the [Guide](https://20https://github.com/COVESA/dlt-daemon/blob/master/doc/dlt_demo_setup.md)

I installed dlt viewer UI which can be viewed by

> dlt-viewer

command .

**Issue :**
I am facing issue to connect DLT deamon to this dlt viewer UI(to view logs here ) as in the Dlt viewer [Guide](https://github.com/COVESA/dlt-viewer/blob/master/INSTALL.md)   it is not specified about connecting local host to the DLT viewer .? I tried to connect by creating ECU but it does not work . Please Help.

Link to my [repo](https://github.com/aazaad29/DLT--CMAKE-/tree/main/module2)

[image]